# How to open a separate angular project as a popup inside another angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application

We have a suite of 4-5 mature angular applications as separate projects residing in their own separate repos. We want to add same feature to all of these apps. The feature is orthogonal to core functionality of parents apps and includes a fairly complicated UI. We want to create feature application in a separate project and repo, so it can evolve on its own.

To incorporate feature app in parent app, one way is to provide a link (menu) and on click, redirect user to feature app (with single sign-on). Once done, they can be redirected back to parent application. BUT it is desirable that if user clicks a button, feature app should open as a popup.

How do we create an angular application as a separate project in its own repo and open it as a popup in a parent application?

Important Note - We would like to avoid using iframes. Also, existing parent applications are in angular and with mature code base (2-3 years of dev on average). We don't want to drastically change these apps. We are flexible framework choice in feature app, but angular is preferred.

Comment: Maybe module federation is an option for you?

Comment: More on module federation: https://just-another-developer.medium.com/module-federation-angular-12-beginners-guide-with-example-677e0c0543fd